# Recommend book on elementary geometry

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, book-recommendation

I am seeking recommendations for books on elementary geometry, including Euclidean geometry and analytic geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm only 15, but my mom bought me and my sisters 'Life Of Fred' math books, and I really like them. They have a geometry math book that you can check out, but I do not own it so I haven't read it to make sure that it has everything.

I read the website page (https://www.lifeoffred.uniquemath.com/lof-geometry.php#.XsaIsmhKguU) and it says it has Euclidean geometry. The life of Fred series is so good that I wouldn't doubt that it is great.

I hope this helps, but it's mostly just my opinion and I think I read that I'm not supposed to answer with my opinion. (I'm sure this question is an exception though.)

Comment: I formatted your text. It was causes by the spaces you made at the beginning of every paragraph.

Comment: *"I think I read that I'm not supposed to answer with my opinion"*. Well remembered but you're right that there are a few possible exceptions such as this (e.g., questions tagged as [soft-question] or reference requests).